# Compiled with a different version - Delphi, Indy 10 Issue

Tags: delphi, indy

I have a very stressful problem in my project, I do not have much experience with Delphi to allow me to solve this myself. I'm trying to send a JSON to a service that will return another JSON. After I implemented the code for this my project does not compile any more.

```
[DCC Error] LancadorApps.pas(13): F2051 Unit IdServerIOHandler was compiled with a different version of IdIOHandler.TIdIOHandler
```

I did some research but I could not solve my problem.

Comment: I deleted the Dcu's and tried to recompile the project
[DCC Error] dGlobal.pas(21): F1026 File not found: 'IdIOHandlerStack.dcu'

Comment: Search this site for the phrase `[delphi] unit was compiled with a different version`.

Comment: Sounds like your project's search paths are not setup correctly